# Getting values based on other column

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, window-functions, sql-null

I have the following data in SQL.

```
NAME,DATE,REF


Pat1,2021-07-15,5072

'',NULL,5072

'',NULL,5072

'',NULL,5072

'',NULL,5072

Pat2,2021-07-15,5073
```

Is there a way using SELECT QUERY that we can replace the NULL values in DATE column based on the REF values?

Like replace the NULL values with the first available date for matching REF value, without making any change to the database.

Expected Result

```
NAME,DATE,REF




Pat1,2021-07-15,5072

'',2021-07-15,5072

'',2021-07-15,5072

'',2021-07-15,5072

'',2021-07-15,5072

Pat2,2021-07-15,5073
```

Comment: Can a "ref" have different dates?'

Comment: 'REF' will not have different dates in in this case.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)   Sep 24 2019 13:48:23   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0 <X64> (Build 18363: )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `MAX()` window function:

```
SELECT NAME,
       COALESCE(DATE, MAX(DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY REF)) DATE,
       REF
FROM tablename
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a25a71cc5f08fa1fb31519b8f590f2fb).

Comment: What if REF is an alias column?

Comment: @ManishKumar then instead of REF you should use the original column in the PARTITION BY clause.

Comment: its something like this for REF "COALESCE(TABLE1.REF,TABLE2.REF,TABLE3.REF,TABLE4.REF) AS REF"

Comment: @ManishKumar `PARTITION BY COALESCE(TABLE1.REF,TABLE2.REF,TABLE3.REF,TABLE4.REF)`

Answer (score 0):

Have a *derived table* (the subquery) to return each ref's date. `JOIN`:

```
select t1.NAME, t2.date, t1.REF
from tablename t1
join (select ref, max(date) date
      from tablename
      group by ref) t2
  on t1.ref = t2.ref
```

Comment: Can it be done with CASE WHEN or ISNULL ?

Comment: I guess so, but this is better.

Comment: I already have multiple joins to get this result. Can you try it without Join?

Comment: Take a look at @forpas answer!